# progress bar is not hiding is when the data is loaded in recyclerview in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I created an interface and extended to  the class

```
class MoviesandTv(override var mprogressdialog: Dialog) : Fragment() , CDialogs {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.moviesandtv, container, false)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    mlinearLayoutManagerrr = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    mlinearLayoutManagerrr!!.reverseLayout = true
    mlinearLayoutManagerrr!!.stackFromEnd = true
    rc_listing_movies_tv = view.rc_list_movies_tv
    showCustomProgressDialog()
    showdata_movies()

    return view
}
```

And hide my dialog bar on onbinderview when the data is loaded

fun showdata_movies(){

```
    optionsss = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Data>().setQuery(db_movies, Data::class.java).build()

    mfirebaseRecyclerAdapterrr = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, ViewHolder_Movies_TV>(optionsss!!) {
        override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHoldermovies: ViewHolder_Movies_TV, i: Int, model: Data) {
            hideCustomProgressDialog()
            viewHoldermovies.setDetails(activity, model.movie_title, model.review, model.date)
```

But is only  shows the dialog box and does no hide it from onbnderview

my implemented method are

```
override  fun showCustomProgressDialog() {
    mprogressdialog = context.let { Dialog(it!!) }
    mprogressdialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog)
    mprogressdialog.show() }


override fun hideCustomProgressDialog() {
    mprogressdialog!!.dismiss()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, the option that you have is to override the following method and hide the `ProgressBar`, like in the following lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged() {
    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, your solution really helped me. i just called that method right below of Binderview  and it did the job , thank you so much

Comment: i have a new issue - trying to get the shared intent done on the app but since i am using recylceradapter  it is not letting me the  model.title or image object 
i have asked the question here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64459751/impalement-share-intent-using-firebase-recycler-adapter

please help me understand.

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.