# Iimpalement share intent, using Firebase recycler adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-intent

I am using FirebaseRecylcerAdapter, trying to share the image or data of my RecylcerView to other apps using share intent

below is my adapter where I am trying to get the button onclick:

```
  private fun ShowData() {
   var tip =  mfirebasedatabase!!.getReference("Model").orderByChild("a")
    options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>().setQuery(tip, Model::class.java).build()
    mfirebaseRecyclerAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(options!!) {
        override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, i: Int, model: Model) {
            viewHolder.setDetails(applicationContext, model.image, model.title)
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val itemview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
            val viewHolder = ViewHolder(itemview)
            var sh :Button = itemview.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttontoShare)
            sh.setOnClickListener {
              // how to get the Model.image so that i can implement
                //share intent to share data to other apps?

            }
```

Please help me understand how to  get the object from there

Answer (score 0):

The `model` object that you get as an argument in the `onBindViewHolder()` method cannot be used in `onCreateViewHolder()` method because is out of scope. If you need to set on click listener on the `sh` button, set it in the `ViewHolder` class rather than in `onCreateViewHolder` method. In this way, you can access the `model` object because is already send into that class earlier, when you have used:

```
viewHolder.setDetails(applicationContext, model.image, model.title)
```

In that way, you can attach the listener and send the clicked object to the next activity. However, a more appropriate way of solving this would be to use a callback, as explained in this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/WeatherApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/weatherapp/adapters/CityAdapter.java).